# SSRS 2008 - Report viewer - asp.net application - JS Error (tNode is null or not an object)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have an asp.net web application using the ReportViewer2008-SP1 controls to display some reports from the SSRS ReportServer.  On some of the reports, i am seeing a JS error - "tNode is null or not an object". I am not sure if this has anything to do with the problem, but these reports have the tablix control being used in them. the error doesnt happen on reports that use a table control instead of the tablix control.

any suggestions about how to work around this issue, will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem last week only with reports that included a **Document Map**. I figured out **AsyncRendering** property of my Report Viewer should be set to true in order to work without any JS errors.